# Amazon SES, understand errors and avoid suspension

Tags: amazon-web-services, spam-prevention, amazon-ses

I started using Amazon SES to send newsletters (more than 30k emails). I have 2 problems.

**Errors**

I receive lots of errors like these:

```
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 554 4.4.7 Message expired: unable to deliver in 840 minutes.<421 4.4.0 Unable to lookup DNS for DOMAIN.it>
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 554 4.4.7 Message expired: unable to deliver in 840 minutes.<421 <CASELLA@alice.it> Service not available - too busy>
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 554 4.4.7 Message expired: unable to deliver in 840 minutes.<421 4.4.1 Failed to establish connection>
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 554 4.4.7 Message expired: unable to deliver in 840 minutes.<421 4.4.2 Connection timed out>
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 4.4.7 Message expired: unable to deliver in 840 minutes.<421 4.4.2 Connection closed unexpectedly>
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 554 4.4.7 Message expired: unable to deliver in 840 minutes.<421 4.4.0 Unable to lookup DNS for ANOTHERDOMAIN.191.it>
```

Especially this error:

```
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 554 4.4.7 Message expired: unable to deliver in 840 minutes.<421 4.4.0 Unable to lookup DNS for sitedomain.it>
```

I've replaced the domains to protect privacy, but errors refer to different domains.

To see them, I have "return-path". Before using Amazon, I was using a private SMTP and I didn't ever receive those messages.

It seems like lots of addresses are wrong or inexistent, but why I didn't get them before?

What's the explanation?

**High Spamassassin Score**

I used this tool: http://spamcheck.postmarkapp.com/ to check the quality of emails sent and the score is always between 3 and 5.

My emails are only HTML and contain only links to my commercial website. They are news,offers or similar things for my clients (they opted in the newsletter).

I have DKIM enabled for the domain.

How can I produce a better HTML to lower the spamassasin score and avoid spam?

This is the full message including full headers and content:

```
Content-Filter: maildrop-toaster
Return-Path: <0000014c703b095b-d06c5ff8-cabd-409e-96ed-187a8a98157e-000000@eu-west-1.amazonses.com>
Delivered-To: clientdomain.it-info@clientdomain.it
Return-Path: <0000014c703b095b-d06c5ff8-cabd-409e-96ed-187a8a98157e-000000@eu-west-1.amazonses.com>
X-Spam-Flag: YES
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.2.5 (2008-06-10) on mail3.clientdomain.it
X-Spam-Level: **************************************************
X-Spam-Status: Yes, score=50.1 required=5.0 tests=AWL,DNS_FROM_AHBL_RHSBL,
    HTML_IMAGE_RATIO_04,HTML_MESSAGE,MIME_HTML_ONLY,OROLOGIO1,RDNS_NONE
    autolearn=disabled version=3.2.5
X-Spam-Report: 
    *  2.0 DNS_FROM_AHBL_RHSBL RBL: Envelope sender listed in dnsbl.ahbl.org
    *   50 OROLOGIO1 URI: OROLOGIO1
    *  0.2 HTML_IMAGE_RATIO_04 BODY: HTML has a low ratio of text to image area
    *  0.0 HTML_MESSAGE BODY: HTML included in message
    *  1.7 MIME_HTML_ONLY BODY: Message only has text/html MIME parts
    *  0.1 RDNS_NONE Delivered to trusted network by a host with no rDNS
    * -3.9 AWL AWL: From: address is in the auto white-list
Delivered-To: clientdomain.it-info@clientdomain.it
Received: (qmail 24091 invoked by uid 89); 31 Mar 2015 14:34:55 -0000
Received: by simscan 1.4.0 ppid: 24076, pid: 24088, t: 0.0709s
         scanners:none
Received: from unknown (HELO a6-10.smtp-out.eu-west-1.amazonses.com) (54.240.6.10)
  by mail3.clientdomain.it with SMTP; 31 Mar 2015 14:34:55 -0000
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; q=dns/txt; c=relaxed/simple;
    s=uku4taia5b5tsbglxyj6zym32efj7xqv; d=amazonses.com; t=1427812059;
    h=Date:From:To:Message-Id:Subject:Mime-Version:Content-Type:Feedback-ID;
    bh=5bGosed0XiWcFgHNXhhXU4e1wN6LXAXi91I3/eH9smI=;
    b=YA3ERPB8ZTKHSwT8GdA9o2cFZlvNLhiOSPTDjAXS8k6CegLLOWyRAKlZF3So6CSW
    rVLUgkYcCVn/Mi7+Ds2afv8uonP93Quh7rTmVjz4JU7dm3HbiUQd3J8ApDqwz2fZ5y0
    uCOba0L88jzsiWJJraMnbP/zM+IHUpLusbHd+U1s=
Date: Tue, 31 Mar 2015 14:27:39 +0000
From: mydomain Italia <mydomain.italia@mydomain.it>
To: info@clientdomain.it
Message-ID: <0000014c703b095b-d06c5ff8-cabd-409e-96ed-187a8a98157e-000000@eu-west-1.amazonses.com>
Subject: ***SPAM*** Eventi mydomain Italia 2015 
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
X-SES-Outgoing: 2015.03.31-54.240.6.10
Feedback-ID: 1.eu-west-1.z7yglAL5GywH6H26FcViauiBZKVY/EL6nMHx51tLzEY=:AmazonSES
X-Spam-Prev-Subject: Eventi mydomain Italia al  2015 

<html>
  <head>
    <title>Newsletter</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body { font: normal 13px Verdana; width: 800px; }
    #footer {
      background: #DCE4FD;
      padding: 10px;
    }

  </style>
  </head>
  <body>

<!--          /* Client-specific Styles */          #outlook a {padding:0;} /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" menu link. */          body{width:100% !important; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%; margin:0; padding:0;}          /* Prevent Webkit and Windows Mobile platforms from changing default font sizes, while not breaking desktop design. */          .ExternalClass {width:100%;} /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */          .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;} /* Force Hotmail to display normal line spacing.  More on that: http://www.emailonacid.com/forum/viewthread/43/ */          #backgroundTable {margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important; line-height: 100% !important;}          img {outline:none; text-decoration:none;border:none; -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;}          a img {border:none;}          .image_fix {display:block;}          p {margin: 0px 0px !important;}                    table td {border-collapse: collapse;}          table { border-collapse:collapse; mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt; }          /*a {color: #e95353;text-decoration: none;text-decoration:none!important;}*/          /*STYLES*/          table[class=full] { width: 100%; clear: both; }                    /*################################################*/          /*IPAD STYLES*/          /*################################################*/          @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {          a[href^="tel"], a[href^="sms"] {          text-decoration: none;          color: #ffffff; /* or whatever your want */          pointer-events: none;          cursor: default;          }          .mobile_link a[href^="tel"], .mobile_link a[href^="sms"] {          text-decoration: default;          color: #ffffff !important;          pointer-events: auto;          cursor: default;          }          table[class=devicewidth] {width: 440px!important;text-align:center!important;}          table[class=devicewidthinner] {width: 420px!important;text-align:center!important;}          table[class="sthide"]{display: none!important;}          img[class="bigimage"]{width: 420px!important;height:219px!important;}          img[class="col2img"]{width: 420px!important;height:258px!important;}          img[class="image-banner"]{width: 440px!important;height:106px!important;}          td[class="menu"]{text-align:center !important; padding: 0 0 10px 0 !important;}          td[class="logo"]{padding:10px 0 5px 0!important;margin: 0 auto !important;}          img[class="logo"]{padding:0!important;margin: 0 auto !important;}           }          /*##############################################*/          /*IPHONE STYLES*/          /*##############################################*/          @media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {          a[href^="tel"], a[href^="sms"] {          text-decoration: none;          color: #ffffff; /* or whatever your want */          pointer-events: none;          cursor: default;          }          .mobile_link a[href^="tel"], .mobile_link a[href^="sms"] {          text-decoration: default;          color: #ffffff !important;           pointer-events: auto;          cursor: default;          }          table[class=devicewidth] {width: 280px!important;text-align:center!important;}          table[class=devicewidthinner] {width: 260px!important;text-align:center!important;}          table[class="sthide"]{display: none!important;}          img[class="bigimage"]{width: 260px!important;height:136px!important;}          img[class="col2img"]{width: 260px!important;height:160px!important;}          img[class="image-banner"]{width: 280px!important;height:68px!important;}                    }        -->
<div><!-- Start of preheader --> 
<table id="backgroundTable" style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#f6f4f5">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="100%">
<table class="devicewidth" style="width: 580px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
<tbody>
<!-- Spacing --> 
<tr>
<td width="100%" height="5">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<!-- Spacing --> 
<tr>
<td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: #999999;" align="right" valign="middle"><a href='http://www.myseconddomain.it/notizie/2014-nord' target="_blank"></a>i</td>
</tr>
<!-- Spacing --> 
<tr>
<td width="100%" height="5">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<!-- Spacing -->
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<!-- End of preheader --></div>
<div><!-- start of header --> 
<table id="backgroundTable" style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#f6f4f5">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<table class="devicewidth" style="width: 580px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" bgcolor="#0db9ea">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><!-- logo --> 
<table class="devicewidth" style="width: 280px; height: 131px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="logo" style="padding: 10px 0 10px 20px;" width="270" valign="middle">
<div><a href="http://www.mydomain.it" target="_blank"><img style="float: left; border: 1px #f6f4f5;" src="http://bit.ly/logomydomain" alt="" width="233" height="107" /></a></div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<!-- End of logo --> <!-- menu --> 
<table class="devicewidth" style="width: 287px; height: 74px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="right">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="menu" style="font-family: Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #ffffff; line-height: 24px; padding: 10px 0px; text-align: right;" colspan="2" width="270" valign="middle">Gioved&igrave; 02/04/2015<br /><a href="http://www.mydomain.it" target="_blank"><img style="float: left; border: 1px #f6f4f5;" src="http://www.mydomain.it/system/media/img/passion.jpg" alt="" width="287" height="74" /></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div>
<table id="backgroundTable" style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#f6f4f5">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<table class="devicewidth" style="width: 580px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="100%" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table class="devicewidthinner" style="width: 540px; border: 0px solid #ffffff;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<!-- start of image -->
<td align="center"><a href='http://www.myseconddomain.it/notizie/mydomain-ti-invita-al--a-milano' target="_self" title=" 2015"><img style="border: 1px solid white;" src="http://www.mydomain.it/system/media/news/2015/marzo/solanNL1.jpg" alt="" width="541" height="299" /></a></td>
</tr>
<!-- end of image --> <!-- Spacing --> 
<tr>
<td width="100%" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<!-- Spacing --> <!-- title --> 
<tr>
<td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; color: #333333; text-align: left; line-height: 20px;">Fiera di Roma 8-10 aprile 2015<br /></td>
</tr>
<!-- end of title --> <!-- Spacing --> <!-- Spacing --> <!-- content --> 
<tr>
<td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 13px; color: #95a5a6; text-align: left; line-height: 24px;">
<p><strong>mydomain Italia &egrave; lieta di invitarLa ai due seguenti incontri</strong><em> </em></p>
<p><strong>9 aprile ore 16.00</strong> <em>- "Il distributore 2.0 e il ruolo degli installatori" &egrave; rivolto  ad installatori, operatori del settore. Introduzione e moderazione a cura di Maurizio.<br /></em></p>
<p><strong>10 aprile ore 10.00</strong> -<em> "Industria e retail: la diagnosi energetica quale elemento chiave per la  competitivit&agrave;" &egrave; rivolto ad industrie, retail, grande distribuzione organizzata, energy manager.</em></p>
<p><strong>Richiedi i biglietti omaggio al tuo referente commerciale</strong><em><br /></em></p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100%" height="10">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table class="tablet-button" style="height: 30px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="left">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="background-color: #0db9ea; border-top-left-radius: 4px; border-bottom-left-radius: 4px; border-top-right-radius: 4px; border-bottom-right-radius: 4px; background-clip: padding-box; font-size: 13px; font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; text-align: center; color: #ffffff; font-weight: 300; padding-left: 18px; padding-right: 18px;" width="auto" height="30" align="center" valign="middle"><a href='http://www.myseconddomain.it/notizie/mydomain-ti-invita-al--a-milano' target="_self" title=" 2015"><span style="color: #ffffff; font-weight: 300;">&nbsp;Leggi di pi&ugrave; </span></a></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100%" height="20">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<!-- button --> <!-- /button --> <!-- Spacing --> <!-- Spacing -->
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<div><!-- start textbox-with-title --><!-- end of textbox-with-title --></div>
<div><!-- start of left image --><!-- end of left image --></div>
<div><!-- start of left image --><!-- end of left image --></div>
<div><!-- fulltext --> <!-- end of fulltext --></div>
<div><!-- Start of 2-columns --><!-- End of 2-columns --></div>
<div><!-- 3-columns --><!-- end of 3-columns --></div>
<div><!-- Full + text --></div>
<div><!-- Start of preheader -->
<div>
<table id="backgroundTable" style="width: 100%;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#f6f4f5">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="100%">
<table class="devicewidth" style="width: 580px;" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td width="100%" height="5">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="font-family: Helvetica, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 10px; color: #999999;" align="center" valign="middle">Se non desideri pi&ugrave; ricevere quetsa mail <a href="http://www.mydomain.it/newsletter/unsubscribe?e=VjNVT2NYRjlNOGRlSnpmYzRiaTZ5aVZHbmFTVXR0RkhjQjAyN05NTUoyYWYrS2JEWjBwbllFQ0RDREYrCkV5bjdWNURWbE1PVzR6aHhkK081MHFndzl4MHdXb2ZsOHhRM1FkN1ROK3ErbllhNlRWWERnK0lJS2V5cgoxYmNVRW4vY3JGT1dYS0l3My9ZMlczcGdXTEE2YzU2dit3SENIUGs4d2VUYU9RaEVLdk0weXhZY2pOV3YKZ2F0a1RTaFVUVVJPTEQ4djFteDFrU1BkMnd2S2pRMXdYaXhia3YyZjdScW5FYk03Y2x1ZEpSSXQvWmMvCjhhQ25MYlJnOWtVQ0RGMmNvN09hWFFFYWtFemZSZjE5bXVkYjNobE11ei9LUDFZanpWeVdpdGRaUzJKbwp1OGQ5ZmZ5S3pUR0FpTkZUaUlpSFY2QWowdjdCOFFlemREVk56S3E3dUE9PQo=">clicca qui</a><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100%" height="5">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
<!-- End of preheader --></div>



  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be a programming question. Debugging external spam problems is too broad for [so]

Comment: There are lots of other messages regarding amazon ses and its usage. I don't see violation here. I'm asking feedback and If you can't provide it, would be better for you if you don't waste your time here. ;)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I see is that the SpamAssassin server is using ahbl.org  which is NOT an active blacklist server.

**On Jan 1 2015 they changed their blacklists so that ALL queries respond with a positive result for spam.**  Is that one of your servers that you are using to test spamassassin?  If so then update your blacklists with current ones.  That'll save you 2 points on your spamassassin score right there.

They posted a message about it here.
http://www.ahbl.org/content/last-notice-wildcarding-services-jan-1st

To address your other concerns about the SES logs

> <421 4.4.0 Unable to lookup DNS for DOMAIN.it>

That means that Amazon SES could not find that domain's DNS record.  Are you sure it is valid?  Check the MX record on http://www.mxtoolbox.com   Amazon SES gives more feedback than other SMTP servers.  It is possible that before those same emails were failing but you were not getting the log data to tell you about it.

Comment: Hello greg, I really appreciated your message. I'm taking a look at those things and I'll update you on what I will do. Have a nice day

Answer (score 0):

For all those who have a problem with this status code and using SMTP:

> smtp; 554 4.4.7 Message expired: unable to deliver in 840 minutes.<421
> IP=xxx.xxx.xxxx.xxxx - No more parallel connections from your address
> allowed>

You can fix this by using the same SmtpClient instance instead of individual ones for the sending process. This way, only one connection is kept open instead of always opening new ones.

In my case, parallel connections to T-online emails were blocked.
With a SmtpClient Singleton it worked and the emails could be delivered successfully.